# Traingular inequality for $L_\infty$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider $f$ which is a measurable function on $X$. We define
$\|f\|_{\infty} = \inf \ \{a \geq 0: \mu(\{x:|f(x)| > a \}) = 0\}$ with the convention that $\inf \phi = 0$. Define $L^{\infty} = \{ f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: f \ \text{is measurable and}\ \|f\|_\infty < \infty \}$.

Show that $\|.\|_{\infty}$ defines a norm on $L^\infty$.

I need help with proving the triangular inequality. I have been able to show the other two properties.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $|f(x)| \le a$ almost everywhere and $|g(x)| \le b$ almost everywhere, then $|f(x) + g(x)| \le \ldots$